# How can i gain more space in one activity (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, scrollview, space

I wanna do activity whitch have buttoms instead R1-16 in this diagram, but i have not enough space. 
I was thinking over the scrollview layout but I don't know how to make the screen can be moved down and to the right. Any idea how can i do this ?

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObRih.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this. I hope it will help you:
https://github.com/myntra/droid-uiscrollview

Comment: Thank's a lot, but how can i add this to my app ? i'm begginer and 
I tried for about 2 hours and nothing came out of it :( I wanna have this in only one activity.

Comment: add 
compile 'com.greycellofp:DroidUIScrollView:1.0.0' 
into your graddle dependency. Then just use <DroidUIScrollView> on your markup.